# Feature test Rails engine using current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm breaking a big Rails app into pieces using mountable engines.

My engine accesses the current user in a controller like so:

```
require_dependency "lesson_notes/application_controller"

module LessonNotes
  class NotesController < ApplicationController

    def index
      @notes = current_user.notes
    end

  end
end
```

In a feature spec I would normally create a user using FactoryGirl and then log the user in - something like this:

```
feature "Notes page" do
  let(:user) { create(:user) }

  before do
    login_as user
    visit "/lesson_notes"

  end
end
```

However, in the engine feature spec, how do I create the user using FactoryGirl? That model is in the parent app in which the engine is mounted, so how is it accessible from my engine specs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could access the parent app's model by writing my factory this way:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, class: "::User" do # Notice the way User is namespaced
    email "test@test.com"
    password "asterisk"
    first_name "James"
    last_name "Baldwin"
    association :user_type, factory: :user_type
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, engine is separate box from main application and which will be mounted in any application, hence it's test cases should also be independent of those.

May be you should mock user model to test your engine's feature instead of creating it from factory.

Comment: That sounds right to me. How do you mock the current_user in RSpec? Or would you somehow mock the session? I'm still relatively new to this.